# Substring in ssrs report expression

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, report

I want to sub string in ssrs report.

```
Original String = 2015-09-01 00:00:00.000
destination String = 01-Sept
```

Please provide the best way.

Answer (score 2):

Another Oneliner and much simple code for the same,

```
OriginalString = "2015-09-01 00:00:00.000"
destinationString = Format(CDate(OriginalString), "dd-MMM")
```

Hope this helps as an alterantive.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using ParseExact will help ?

```
Dim dt = DateTime.ParseExact(youroriginaldate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Nothing)
CStr(dt.ToString("dd-MMMM"))
```

Comment: Thanks Camille, Where can i write the above? I mean in the expression block?